# Передача локальных переменных

Tags: python

Как вернуться обратно в первую функцию со второй?
Допустим:

```
def one(name):
    name=input()
    fine=name
    print(fine)
    two(fine)
def two(fine):
    print(f'{fine}, прекрасное имя')
    one()
one(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

Возвращение произойдет само, как только завершится функция два. Последнюю строку в функции надо убрать (я её закомментировал), иначе будет бесконечный цикл (точнее, углубляющаяся спираль), который, впрочем, будет прерван автоматически системой.
Разумеется, про бесконечный цикл верно при условии, что на `input()` будет
постоянная реакция того, кто вводит:-)

```
def one(name):
    name=input()
    fine=name
    print(fine)
    two(fine)
def two(fine):
    print(f'{fine}, прекрасное имя')
    # one()
one(input())
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: А если у меня допустим 3 функции и мне надо со 2 попасть в 3 и с 3 во 2 до какого-то момента, как можно такое сделать?

Comment: Зависит от конкретики, но в общем случае они все будут возвращаться по цепочке, ровно так же, как и вызывали друг друга. Чуть упрощая: все эти вызовы кладутся последовательно на стек поверх друг друга, а потом так же снимаются последовательно, начиная с последнего. Но важно отследить, чтобы такие вызовы не были бесконечными и однажды закончились. Ваш условный код выше - пример того, где такое не отслеживается:-) И лучше таким не злоупотреблять (<https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/dzen-python-pep20>).